# Stuck in infinite loop while trying to find nth root of x

Tags: c++, math, root

```
    double power(double base, int exponent){
        //Just for context, a double is larger than a long long int
        //Also method programmed to assume non-decimal, non-negative input for root
        double answer = base;
        if(exponent == 0){
            return 1.0;
        }
        else if(exponent > 0){
            for(int i=1; i<exponent; i++){
                answer*=base;
            }
            return answer;
        }
        else{//if exponent is negative
            for(int i=1; i<exponent*(-1); i++){
                answer*=base;
            }
            return 1/answer;
        }
    }
    double newtonRaphsonRoot(double base, int root){//FOR FIDING ROOTS OF CONSTANT #s
        if(base == 1){
            return 1.0;
        }
        //Formula: x1 = x0 - f(x0)/f'(x0)
        //--------------------------------
        //Also method programmed to assume non-negative integer input for root
        double epsilon=0.01;//accuracy
        double answer = base;//answer starts off as initial guess and becomes better approximated each iteration
        if(base > 1){
            answer=base/2;
        }
        while( answer - ( power(answer,root) - base)/(root*power(answer,root-1) ) > epsilon){
        //Formula: x1 = x0 - f(x0)/f'(x0). Continue formula until error is less than epsilon
            answer = answer - ( power(answer,root) - base)/(root*power(answer,root-1) );
            std::cout<<"Approximation: answer = "<< answer <<"\n";
        }
        return answer;
    }
```

- There is a mathematical algorithm for calculating the nth root of a number x, known as the Newton-Raphson method for approximating roots. I tried to program this algorithm. Long story short it seems I'm getting the right answer but
  Problem 1: I'm stuck in the while and I don't know why
  Problem 2: The accuracy was supposed to be determined by variable epsilon, but answer always comes out to 5 places after decimal.*

Comment: We need `power` to get a minimum reproducible example, or code won't compile.

Comment: alright @LouisGo will add

Comment: Also you may extract your condition in loop as a variable and put breakpoint to see why it doesn't work. Eg:  while( next_iter_ans > epsilon ){  .... nextIterAns = your condition}

Comment: If the term to the left of the `>` ever goes negative, it will stay negative.   Usually the NewtonRaphson technique compares absolute values, so is always comparing two positive values (where hopefully one converges to zero, so will eventually be less than `epsilon`).   However, depending on the nature of the inputs - and on rounding errors - it is quite feasible that convergence never happens.   For this reason, it is common (albeit not universal) to also cap the number of iterations - that will catch cases where the (absolute) value being tested never falls below `epsilon`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that to check for epsilon the code should be

```
while (fabs(error) > epsilon) {
    ... improve ...
}
```

you are instead checking the next approximation against epsilon (also without `fabs`).

The other problem is that output stream uses a fixed number of decimals when printing floating point values, if you want to increase that you need to look for `std::setprecision` (or just use `printf("%.18g\n", x);` that is what I personally prefer to do).